# Tomcat Global Time taken to process the request

Tags: tomcat, ddos

When I use %T in the AccessLogValve of server.xml, I do not get the *global* time to process the HTTP request, I get only the *internal* time (i.e. between the acceptation into the threads pool and the response writing).
For instance, during a ddos attack, the request could wait - let say 40 sec - before a thread become available to process it, and %T does not reflect this delay. 
Is there a way to capture it into accessLog file or to calculate it in java ?
Thanks by advance & Sorry for my English !

Comment: Please add any code that you have so that it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from within Tomcat. Tomcat can't start timing until it starts to process the request so the time spent in the accept queue is lost.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will try to find out another way to capture this essential information.